# Trying to delineate areas (riparian zones) from a DEM, with same height difference to a polyline (reach)

Tags: qgis, line, buffer, altitude, average

I'm trying to delineate riparian zones.

The idea is to define a mean depth of the drainage net (constant), and then, draw a buffer around the reaches that will include all the terrain within this average depth. Lets say 1,5 meters above the drainage line.

I have a DEM and the drainage network

Following an scheme of what I'm looking for, I hope it helps.

[image]

In 3d it will work intersecting a plane paralel to the reach (in z dimension) with the terrain model.

I was thinking about searching the nearest point to the reach with a height of 1,5m more than the reach.

Comment: What data do you have? Do you know the depths? Are there different depths along your network, or is it uniform? Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve? Please edit your question accordingly, thank you.

Comment: hello @Erik, I've updated the question. Thank you

Comment: I would: Split the line into segments of maybe 100 m, buffer them, zonal stats to get a height value on each buffer segment, convert to raster, calc difference between this and DEM, contour polygons relative to the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much @bera, I had to play a little withe the saga rasterizing to get a continuous raster of the height diffrenece, but at the end everything was perfect. thank you again

Comment: Nice! I think you should answer your own question and add some screenshots showing the result

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please don’t include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was based on creating a raster layer with the elevation difference from the DEM to the plane of the drainage reaches axis. Then, the required values of elevation difference were issolated and dissolved to obtain the riaparian zones layer.

The process was:

(1) Split features (drainage reaches) by maximum length (50m)

(2) Update id

(3) Buffer splitted features 0.5 m each side

(4) Zonal statistics: for the 1 m buffered features with mean elevation from DEM

(5) Buffer splitted features: 25 m each side

(6) Join by field value (id): adding mean elevation from the 1m wide buffers to the 50m wide buffers

(7) Saga rasterize: 50m wide buffer with mean elevation; cell size 10 m

(8) Raster calculator: elevation difference = MDT - rasterized buffers

(9) Polygonize: new elevation difference raster layer

(10) Select by expresion the required elevation difference polygons

(10) Dissolve selected to create the riparian zones layer

[image]